# how to remove toolbar in custom tabs(plugin of android

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

see custom tab [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/custom-tabs-client) i want to remove the complete this blue section ,actually i don't want those option and link to displayed in my custom tab[image: see these screen shot]. i don't want to show these option in my custom tab. any help ?? . i try to set them to invisible in its layout xml code

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Trusted Web Activities](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/trusted-web-activity/) instead. This does require that you own the website you are displaying.

Otherwise displaying full-screen can only be done with the deprecated [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView).

Answer (score -1):

The key is in your styles.xml file. 
Notice how mine says, NoActionBar

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just set the styles.xml and activity_main.xml properties to any NoActionBar theme. There is second way within MainActivity place this line above setContentView() method:

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Check this link for more info:
http://easyandroidtutorials.com/remove-title-bar-android-hide-action-bar/